# Previous Month Sum of values for a scenario

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Trying to add a summary line for the previous months totals in a tablix where the months are in rows. I get an error.

```
=Previous(Sum(IIf(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value="Activity Actuals",Fields!BOE_volume.Value,0)),"planning_month")
```

The "planning_month" is the Column Group

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add CDEC to the expression to handle any issues with number formatting

```
=Previous(Sum(IIf(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value="Activity Actuals",CDEC(Fields!BOE_volume.Value),CDEC(0))),"planning_month")
```